# Random Size on Featured Image

Tags: images

Hi guys wondering if anyone can help. I have this code that lists all sub pages, their featured image and title/link. What I'd like to be able to do is randomize the the size of the featured image between what Wordpress offers... small/medium/large?

Any ideas?

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
    'parent' => 2,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    ); 
$pages = get_pages($args);  ?>
<ul> 
<?php
foreach( $pages as $page ) {
?>

 <li>
    <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
    <div><span class="thumbnail"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></span>
    <span class="title"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></span></div>
    </a>
</li>
<?php
 }  
?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the sizes into an array and use [PHP's `array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to choose a random size:

```
$sizes = array( 'small', 'medium', 'large' );

foreach( $pages as $page ){
    $random_size = array_rand( $sizes, 1 );
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, $sizes[$random_size] );
}
```